# Consulta de lista de registros mediante clave compuesta

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo una entidad:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="T23FIMP", schema="SMPLIBD")
@IdClass(GrillaMontoEdadId.class)
public class GrillaMontoEdad implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "W23IDT")
    @NotNull
    private Integer IdTabla;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "W23PRO")
    @NotNull
    private Integer producto;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "W23PLA")
    @NotNull
    private String plan;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "W23PLG")
    @NotNull
    private Integer grilla;
    @Column(name = "W23FEC")
    @NotNull
    private Integer fechaVigencia;
    @Column(name = "W23EDD")
    @NotNull
    private Integer edadDesde;
    @Column(name = "W23EDH")
    @NotNull
    private Integer edadHasta;
    @Column(name = "W23CAN")
    @NotNull
    private Integer cantBeneficiarios;
    @Column(name = "W13MOP")
    @NotNull
    private Integer montoPlan;
}
```

El Id compuesto:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GrillaMontoEdadId implements Serializable {

    private Integer producto;
    private String plan;
    private Integer grilla;

}
```

...y necesito hacer una consulta a base de datos para encontrar todos los registros correpondientes a un id determinado, pero no lo logro.

¿Cómo tendría que declararse el método adecuado dentro del repositorio para poder hacer bien esa consulta?

De todas las maneras que intenté, les muestro algunas pero ninguna funcionó:

```
List<GrillaMontoEdad> findAll(GrillaMontoEdadId grillaMontoEdadId);
List<GrillaMontoEdad> findAllById(GrillaMontoEdadId grillaMontoEdadId);
List<GrillaMontoEdad> findAllByGrillaMontoEdadId(GrillaMontoEdadId grillaMontoEdadId);
```

En el primer caso, el id me tira "No property id found for type GrillaMontoEdad!"

La segunda "No property findAll found for type GrillaMontoEdad!"

La tercera "No property montoEdadId found for type Integer! Traversed path: GrillaMontoEdad.grilla."

...ninguna llega a compilar

Comment: Que error te sale al compilar? Por favor inclúyelo en la pregunta yendo a [edit]

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo